# change text inside a modal for specific page url using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

i am new to javascript and wondering how one would solve the following problem.

on my portfolio website each project has its own page.

i have a button called `<button> information </button>` . This button is displayed on every page and opens a modal when you click on it.  the modal contains information about the project you are currently seeing, e. g. title, year and concept of the work. it is all inside a class called `<div class="modal-content" id="content">` .

to make it work i added some lines of javascript and it just works fine. however, i now i want all the text inside  `<div class="modal-content" id="content">` to change, depending on the project-page i am currently on.

any ideas on how one could do this?

looking forward to any helpful tip :)

```
<div class="modal">

 <div class="header">
  <div class="title" id="title">approaching visual</div>
  <div class="year" id="year">2022</div>
  <div class="modal-close">  &times;</div>
 </div>

 <div class="modal-content" id="content">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Iste libero facilis magni iure quae saepe suscipit assumenda quis
  deserunt quasi voluptate voluptatum quo repellendus consequatur,
  eveniet impedit ratione! Repellendus, in? </p>
 </div>

</div>









if (window.location="http://anywebadress.com/amazing-project-2") {
 
    title.textContent = "new project-title";
    year.textContent = "new date";

  };
```

Comment: Where are you holding the texts? Is there a database behind this or are you wanting to build it all into the JavaScript and just select the right text depending on the current page's location?

Comment: @AHaworth there is no database behind it, so the second approach would be the one.

Comment: OK, so it'll be built either to the JS or the HTML (which?). Can you put just enough code into your question so we can see the relevant HTML structure (e.g. to show us what element is title and so on).

Comment: It would be built to the JS. I updated my post and provided my HTML structure. if you need further information, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't see where/how you are storing the texts for each page. Is there some JavaScript array with them in, or will they be direct in the HTML?

Comment: currently i do not store them at all. i only have this one single element in my HTML  (class="modal") which is displayed on page-1 (but also on every other page). on page-2 i want all the text inside the modal to change. i thought about changing it by using the "innerText" method posted down below and writing the alternative text all by myself in JS. then i would repeat this step for every single page. in fact this might be not be the smartest way to do it, but since i am new to JS i would be fine with it. but how can i link the"innerText" function to an if condition (if url shows page-2)?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 best ways to override the data inside any HTML element depends on the use case.

1. **InnerHTML**: This property sets and returns the content of an element with new HTML content.
2. **InnerText**: This property returns the content of all elements, except for  and  elements. The returned content is visible in plain text without any formatting.
3. **TextContent**: This property returns the raw content with styling inside of all elements, but excludes the HTML element tags.

Here is the example of all three methods-

**To change the content using innerHTML-**

```js
let el = document.getElementById("content");
el.innerHTML = "And <strong> NOW </strong> the contents have been changed!";
console.log(el.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="modal-content" id="content"></div>
```

**To change the content using innerText-**

```js
let el = document.getElementById("content");
el.innerText = "And <strong> NOW </strong> the contents have been changed!";
console.log(el.innerText);
```

```html
<div class="modal-content" id="content"></div>
```

**To change the content using textContent-**

```js
let el = document.getElementById("content");
el.textContent = "And <strong> NOW </strong> the contents have been changed!";
console.log(el.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="modal-content" id="content"></div>
```

For your case, I would recommend **innerHTML** if you want to update the HTML of the whole modal and use **innerText** if you want to update only the text.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. appreciate!
however, a question still remains: how can i execute this code only(!) if "page-id = 1234" or URL is "http://anywebadress.com/amazing-project-2" ?

Comment: You can use `includes` method to check if the current URL includes a specific string so you can identify what page it is. For example- `window.location.href.includes('amazing-project')`

Answer (score 0):

Access the elementById's textContent using querySelector.

```
var content = document.getElementById("content")
content.querySelector(".title").textContent = title.textContent
content.querySelector(".year").textContent = year.yearContent
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Select the given div
const content = document.getElementById("content") 

// *** now UPDATE ITS CONTENT ***

//  if "title" and "year" are CLASSES. Use this bellow 
content.querySelector(".title").textContent = title.textContent
content.querySelector(".year").textContent = year.yearContent

//  if "title" and "year" are IDs. Use this bellow  
content.querySelector("#title").textContent = title.textContent
content.querySelector("#year").textContent = year.yearContent
```